# ¿Qué hacer con las preguntas formuladas en inglés o en otro idioma?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, traducciones-de-contenido

Hasta el momento han habido algunas preguntas que se han formulado en inglés.

<sup>* Un caso es la [primera versión (10k+)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2438/1) de una pregunta (que luego fue editada [para traducirla (10k+)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2438/uncaught-exception-pdoexception-with-message-sqlstatehy093-invalid-paramet)).</sup>

He visto que en algunos casos se han hecho ediciones de la pregunta para traducirla al español. Sin embargo, me preocupa que apoye la proliferación de este tipo de preguntas.

¿Qué pasaría en los siguientes casos?

- El autor original, no entiende español.
- El autor original simplemente no quiere hacer el esfuerzo por formularla en español sabiendo que muy probablemente su pregunta será traducida por otro usuario.

¿Y qué deberíamos hacer si alguien que no es el autor:

- Sugiere una traducción del contenido?
- ¿Y si ya se aplicó la edición?

Comment: entiendo tu pregunta, pero para este caso creo que no es aplicables pues el usuario fue el que tradujo la respuesta (o eso creo) pues le pregunte que si habla español me dijo que si y a los pocos minutos estaba en español, por otro lado si la pregunta es en ingles yo no estoy a favor de traducirlas, pero si, si la pregunta es escrita en español pero se nota que es por una persona que no domina el idioma, en este caso si que estoy de acuerdo en que se ajuste para que se entienda bien la pregunta.

Comment: porque creo que se nota cuando la pregunta es escrita por alguien que domine el español pero esta pregunta no tiene sentido, a cuando la pregunta es escrita por un no hablante de español, y con algunos ajustes de puede entender. Saludos

Comment: Si como dice @AngelAngel en este caso el AO fue el que tradujo la pregunta luego de que se le aclarara por comentario que este sitio era en español.

Comment: Yo no la hubiera tocado para nada. Realmente, tal y como adjuntas con la otra respuesta, si no entiende el español no tiene sentido que traduzcamos la pregunta nosotros ya que no entenderá las respuestas. Creo que se debería de revertir la pregunta y dejar que el OP conteste. Aunque hasta entonces la mantendría cerrada y en inglés.

Comment: Si, haría lo que propone @Error404 por que Diana no ha contestado (OP o como se llame), así como también no haría una traducción, por que si no entiende el idioma será una pregunta sin respuesta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Si la pregunta está completamente en otro idioma, no debería ser traducida.  Es poco probable que se pueda educar al usuario si no cumple con la mínima barrera para participar en este sitio, comunicarse en español.  No confiaría de que las respuestas le fueran a ser útiles tampoco.

Si escribe en un español no muy bueno, deberíamos tratar de rescatar la publicación.

Comment: pregunto de ignorante ya que acabo de entrar por primera vez a la version en español (llevo años en la original), pregunto: en review no hay un tag "traducir"?

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta No hay tal tag, pero puedes explicar en un comentario o como parte de la pregunta si tienes algún impedimento para expresar tu pregunta en castellano, esperando que un alma caritativa (que als hay pocas) se compadezca y te ayude.

Answer (score 13):

Para el **caso general**, debería ser el autor de la pregunta el que traduzca la pregunta. Si es otro usuario el que lo traduce, lo recomendable es **no aprobar la edición** (o revertirla si ya es tarde).

El **motivo principal**: gran parte de la lógica del sitio se basa en qué respuesta fue aceptada, y no hay ninguna garantía de que un usuario que no pudo realizar una pregunta en español esté capacitado para evaluar las respuestas.

Pondría, sin embargo, una gran **excepción**: podemos ayudar a un usuario que no hable español, pero que esté haciendo un esfuerzo para preguntar en español (por ejemplo con una mala traducción de Google). Me gustaría pensar que el sitio tiene una política abierta y reciba bien a personas que no hablen español pero lo intenten. De la misma forma, si yo tuviese una pregunta de código muy específica de Japón, me gustaría que me reciban bien en [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) si uso Google y la traducción es mala.

No obstante, también habría que tomar entre pinzas un posible caso: si el autor original **no está registrado**, y la traducción viene de otro usuario nuevo, es muy probable que haya sido el mismo autor el que tradujo la pregunta (y haya perdido las credenciales de ese usuario con el que hizo la pregunta). Son casos para estar atentos, para intentar guiar a los usuarios en los comentarios. En ese caso, ante la duda, conviene reportar a un moderador (que podrá evaluar si son el mismo usuario).

Answer (score 2):

Como bien dice Mariano **generalmente** si encontramos una traducción realizada por un usuario que no sea el OP lo correcto es rechazar la edición.

Hay varias excepciones y una de las que indica Mariano es correcta pero hay otra excepción que entra en este caso y que es importante tener en cuenta.

Como moderador podemos consultar, si la situación lo merece, la localización a partir del IP de cualquier usuario. Eso significa que si vemos una edición de una pregunta en inglés para traducirla y el autor tiene IP de habla española la edición tiene números para avanzar. Es cierto que la localización por IP no es garantía de que el autor realmente hable español pero es un indicador a tener en cuenta.

Fijaos que precisamente yo mismo decidí reabrir algunas preguntas tras ser traducidas, ya que pude comprobar eso mismo que estoy diciendo. Hay que tener cuidado en estos casos (sé que no es fácil) pero si veis que una pregunta ha sido traducida por alguien que no es el autor y luego un *moderador* la reabre, eso significa que **normalmente** hay algún motivo ulterior al respecto. Eso no significa que no me pueda equivocar (que ha pasado).

Comment: Entiendo esta otra excepción, y está genial que puedan identificar por IP (gracias por agregarlo)... pero en este caso, si fue la misma autora la que la tradujo, ¿no estaríamos fomentando preguntas que quedan huérfanas (sin un usuario que pueda aceptar una respuesta)?

Comment: @Mariano es un caso un poco curioso por qué quién hizo la traducción fue un usuario anónimo con IP distinta.. Es probable que sea el mismo usuario pero no hay suficientes pruebas que lo indiquen. Si utilizara la misma IP/usuario registrado/correo o algo podríamos indagar más pero es un usuario anónimo. ¡Gracias por el aviso!

Answer (score 2):

**CASO DE DESPISTE DEL USUARIO**

Por lo que he observado, hay casos en los que la pregunta está claramente destinada al sitio en inglés (enSO).

He visto dos o tres de estos, creo que el usuario se equivocó al poner la URL de SO o hizo una búsqueda en Google en español y vino a parar a esSO... y escribió su pregunta sin más.

Este es un ejemplo reciente: [php, How can i make the summation of variables?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53836/php-how-can-i-make-the-summation-of-variables)

**En ese caso, creo que la mejor opción es reportar la pregunta para que un moderador la traslade a enSO y no votar para que la misma sea cerrada.**

Comment: Una migración no es un proceso tan "aceitado" en la interfaz de SE.. Para que una pregunta sea migrada, debe cumplir las condiciones para que sea una buena pregunta en el sitio destino y que la migración no sea rechazada (un cierre de pregunta rechaza la migración)... Muchas de las preguntas hechas en inglés en SOes no cumplen esta condición, y en ese caso yo recomendaría cerrarlas... Además, cerrando, se le da la opción al autor para que traduzca la pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano De acuerdo contigo en todo, menos en esto: _Además, cerrando, se le da la opción al autor para que traduzca la pregunta_ En el caso que planteo, el autor no tendría ningún interés en traducir la pregunta, ya que es evidente que la formuló en esSO por error.

Answer (score -2):

### En resúmen

El comportamiento esperado es que si es un problema que:

- sea relevante
- pueda ayudar a nuestra comunidad hispanohablante
- nos permita mostrar amplio conocimiento de una tecnología

o de preferencia todas las anteriores, nos permitamos contestarlo y si nos da tiempo, incluso traducirlo, para tener más hits entre los que buscan en nuestro idioma y ser más útiles.

### Acerca de las preguntas secundarias

> El autor original, no entiende español

Por fortuna el sitio es de programación, no de Español, con que entienda el `código de la respuesta`, un `es posible` o un `no es posible` debería de bastar. Si su pregunta es útil a los demás te podría servir contestarla sin importar en que idioma esté.

> El autor original simplemente no quiere hacer el esfuerzo por formularla en español sabiendo que muy probablemente su pregunta será traducida por otro usuario.

Desafortunadamente aún no existe la tecnología para saber si quería o no... o si alguien hará algo o no.
Lo más cordial es asumir que está escribiendo desde un submarino ruso con un teclado con kanjies y que está consiente de que un novato puede hacerse de reputación fácil a costa de traducir la pregunta, sin que eso implique que reciba una respuesta o sea recibido de una manera malinchista ( Xenolovers ) por la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias por contestar a esta pregunta en meta. Iba a dejar un comentario en la pregunta en SOes que ha hecho que respondas aquí, pero no quise porque no estaría relacionada con la pregunta allí. Ahora: creo que tienes un concepto equivocado de lo que StackOverflow en Español es y de lo que se espera de sus usuarios. Confundes tener dificultades con el español (ya sea por dificultades técnicas o de conocimiento) con no utilizar el idioma completamente. No es lo mismo escribir mal por no tener el teclado adecuado o cometer una falta de ortografía, que escribir una pregunta en un idioma "extraño"

Comment: Si en SO en inglés se escribe una pregunta en español, esa pregunta se cierra porque las normas del sitio indican que las preguntas deben estar en inglés. Nadie las traduce incluso cuando hay usuarios que podrían hacerlo fácilmente. ¿Por qué no se va a hacer lo mismo en SOes cuando las normas especifican que el idioma a usar es el español? No se está pidiendo a la gente que escriba como Cervantes o García Márquez, se les pide que escriban en español. No es tan difícil y es un requisito mínimo y aceptable (si quieren preguntar en inglés, ya hay otro sitio en la red de StackExchange para ello)

Comment: No es xenófobo decirle a una persona que este sitio es para preguntas en español. Es normal. No es "no profesional" decirle a una persona que este sitio es en español. Es normal. Está dentro de las normas y los requisitos mínimos en el centro de ayuda. Es normal. Añadir comentarios llamando xenófobos (ya sea de manera irónica o no) es lo que no es normal. Criticar a otros por no ser "humanos" es lo que no es normal. Especialmente porque la manera en la que Luiggi o Carlos comentaron fue, en mi opinión, educada y adecuada (no sólo estaba en inglés sino que incluso traducida es de mala calidad).

Comment: Perdón por los comentarios tan largos. Supongo que lo que quiero decir se reduce a: StackOverflow en Español no es un servicio de traducción, es una sitio para programadores profesionales y entusiastas de la programación en español. Para otros idiomas ya hay otros sitios de la red StackExchange en [inglés](http://stackoverflow.com), [ruso](http://ru.stackoverflow.com), [portugués](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) o [japonés](http://jp.stackoverflow.com), y éste no es el sitio para hacer preguntas en esos idiomas.