# ¿Qué hacer con esta pregunta en inglés, que fue traducida a español por alguien que no es OP?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

La duda concierne la pregunta siguiente: [¿Como encontrar la primera letra y el primer vocal en una cadena?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36668/como-encontrar-la-primera-letra-y-el-primer-vocal-en-una-cadena).

La pregunta fue formulada originalmente en inglés por un nuevo usuario. Como es obvio, la pregunta fue puesto en espera y se le dejó un comentario para determinar si se había equivocado de sitio, si puede traducir la pregunta en español, etc.

Pero entre tanto, un usuario anónimo tradujo la pregunta a español, y la edición fue aprobada. En mi opinión, esto fue un error, sobre todo de parte de los que aprobaron la edición.  Como bien se explica en [esta respuesta aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365/18951):

> Si la pregunta está completamente en otro idioma, no debería ser traducida. Es poco probable que se pueda educar al usuario si no cumple con la mínima barrera para participar en este sitio, comunicarse en español. No confiaría de que las respuestas le fueran a ser útiles tampoco.

Ahora, la pregunta fue reabierta y el comentario a OP fue borrado, y aún no sabemos si OP siquiera entiende español.

¿Qué se debe hacer con la pregunta?