# ¿Cuántos no encontraron la respuesta en Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, idiomas, estadísticas

A los usuarios que tienen un [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) en español, dentro de Stack Overflow (**inglés**)

1. En las preguntas les aparece:

   > [image: ¿No encuentras la respuesta?]
2. Además, los usuarios anónimos que intentan preguntar en SO, llegan a:

   > [image: ¿Prefieres preguntar en español? No es necesario registrarse.]
3. Y, sin importar el Accept-Language, si redactan en SO con un título que coincide con [ciertas palabras](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325866/5290909), les aparece:

   > [image: Si quieres preguntar en español, lo puedes hacer aquí: Stack Overflow en español.]

En particular, son 3 enlaces que se generan con un parámetro especialmente para cada caso:

1. [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?**fromen**=008e3ed011528](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?fromen=008e3ed011528)
2. [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?**fromen**=**fsorl**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?fromen=fsorl)
3. [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?**utm_source**=**soen-es**](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?utm_source=soen-es)

Sin embargo, me parece que el parámetro **se pierde** en los casos 1 y 3, debido a la **redirección** de HTTP a HTTPS.

---

Teniendo en cuenta que son [casi 2 preguntas por día](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats), y que ya tenemos varios intentos por moderar mejor estos casos <sup><sub>([cómo reducirlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/127), [qué hacer](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362/127) y [cómo mejorar el cierre](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1324/127))</sub></sup>, me interesaría saber si se puede:

- Corregir la redirección para no perder el parámetro y obtener estadísticas confiables (Si es que se está perdiendo el parámetro).
- Obtener métricas de cuántos usuarios ingresan a SOes por cada una de estas 3 vías.

  - cuántos registrados y cuántos no registrados.
  - cuántos no registrados crearon una cuenta.
  - cuántos publicaron una pregunta.
  - cuántos publicaron una pregunta que luego fue cerrada con el motivo "*en inglés*".

El objetivo es determinar si esta es la mayor fuente de preguntas publicadas en inglés, y también poder tener un número que nos ayude a entender cuántos usuarios se están captando desde SO por estos medios.

**¿Podrá alguien con acceso a esto compartir los resultados?**

> Nota: no tengo más acceso a [/site-analytics](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), pero creo recordar que no había forma de obtenerlo de ahí (algún mod podrá confirmarme).

Comment: En `/site-analytics` se pueden ver los _traffic sources_, desglosado en _referring sites_ y _search engines_. Sin embargo, no desglosa la página exacta desde la que se llega, sino que simplemente dirá "stackoverflow.com".

Comment: Consulté en Meta SO: [Do we have statistics on how often people asking in different languages get into a localized version of SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365580/1983854).